# GCC/Clang disagree on constrained partial template specialization with out-of-line member definition

Tags: c++, templates, clang, c++20

Consider the following code which creates a partial template specialization that is constrained by a concept.

```
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct Foo { };

template<typename T>
requires std::integral<T>
struct Foo<T> {
    static void bar();
};

template<typename T>
requires std::integral<T>
void Foo<T>::bar() { }

int main() {
    Foo<int>::bar();
}
```

This code compiles without error using gcc 10.2 and MSVC 19.27. However, clang 11.0 errors at the out-of-line definition of bar():

```
<source>:13:15: error: requires clause differs in template redeclaration

requires std::integral<T>

              ^

<source>:3:1: note: previous template declaration is here

template <typename T>
```

If the definition is moved in-line into the partially specialized class, clang does not error.

Is this a bug in clang or does the standard disallow the above code for some reason?

Link to code in godbolt:
https://godbolt.org/z/orsWaP

Comment: Definite clang bug. Filed [48020](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48020).